# I want to get value of Entrybox and Checkbutton but I get nothing why? (I am new to tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter.checkbutton

## I want to get value of Entrybox and Checkbutton but I get nothing why? (I am new to tkinter)

```
from tkinter import *
 
def m1():
    m1 = Tk()
    entry_val = StringVar()
    check_val = IntVar()
    Entry(m1, textvariable=entry_val).pack()
    Checkbutton(m1, text='CheckButton', variable=check_val).pack()

    def show():
        print(entry_val.get())
        print(check_val.get())

    Button(m1, text='click!', command=show).pack()
    m1.mainloop()


def main():
    main = Tk()

    Button(main, text='click! (main)', command=m1).pack()
    main.mainloop()


main()
```

Comment: You must be using TopLevel, as a sidenote

Comment: Why do you have two `Tk` windows running?

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Comment: change `m1 = Tk()` to `m1 = Toplevel()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short and simple answer:

In your code you need to change `m1 = Tk()` to `m1 = Toplevel()`. This will fix your issue.

The long answer:

When writing a Tkinter GUI 99.99% of the time you are only ever going to use 1 tkinter instance `Tk()`. The reason for this is that each instance of `Tk()` is contained within its own personal "Sandbox". Meaning it cannot play with others. So one instance of `Tk()` cannot communicate with a separate `Tk()` instance.

It is my understanding that if you do not specify what instance a method belongs to within the method then it will default to the 1st instance of `Tk()`. So the `StringVar()` and `IntVar()` you have create cannot be printed due to them belonging to `main`. Because `main` cannot talk to `m1` you cannot update this value.

We can actually test this if you change:

```
entry_val = StringVar()
check_val = IntVar()
```

To:

```
entry_val = StringVar(m1)
check_val = IntVar(m1)
```

You will see your variables update properly.

Or if you change `m1 = Tk()` to `m1 = Toplevel()` (the correct solution) you will see that everything works as needed.

`Toplevel()` is specifically designed for creating new windows in tkinter so everything can stay in the same "Sandbox" and work together.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike your answer really helped me, I find solution to my problem.